# Google Datastore entity key id is a string instead of number

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-platform

When I save an entity to the datastore with a numeric key:

```
datastore.save({
  key: datastore.key(['Thing', 123]),
  data: [
    { name: 'name', value: 'My thing' }
  ]
});
```

And then retrieve it again

```
datastore
  .createQuery('Thing')
  .filter('__key__', datastore.key(['Thing', 123]))
  .select('__key__')
  .run((err, entities) => {
    const key = entities[0][datastore.KEY];
    console.log(`key.id = ${key.id}, type = ${typeof key.id}`);
  });
```

This outputs:

```
 key.id = 123, type = string
```

But I'd expect it to output:

```
 key.id = 123, type = number
```

The datastore library seems to go [through great lengths to ensure that the ID is a number](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-node/blob/master/packages/datastore/src/entity.js#L119-L124), but then proceeds to return it as as string. When using the ID to create a new key, e.g.

```
const newKey = datastore.key(['Thing', key.id]);
```

This returns a key that will be unable to find any entities, because the value will be assigned to the `name` instead of the `id` because it's a string.

I've made a small repro case here:
https://github.com/arjenvanderende/datastore-key-id-is-string

It seems very strange to me that the ID is returned as a string instead of a number. Is this expected behaviour or is this a bug in the library?

#### *edit*

This issue becomes a bigger problem when you have a "foreign key" to another object and you use `key.id` to set it. E.g.

```
datastore.save({
  key: datastore.key(['Thing', 234]),
  data: [
    { name: 'name', value: 'My other thing' }
    { name: 'parentThingId', value: thing[datastore.KEY].id }
  ]
});
```

After retrieving this object again from the datastore, looking up the parent of the other thing will fail. Doing a lookup in the datastore with the key `datastore.key(['Thing', otherThing.parentThingId)` will yield no results, because it tries to lookup it up by `name` instead of `id`. It isn't immediately apparent that this is the issue, because types are somewhat hidden in the datastore console.

Answer (score 4):

It is a string, but it is recognized as an `id`. The API does the proper thing when you make future requests with the `key` object.

We have to do some special-case handling in the library, because IDs can be very long-- beyond the allowable ceiling for a JavaScript integer. Our storing it as a string is an internal artifact that should not affect the user.

> When using the ID to create a new key, e.g.
>
> ```
> const newKey = datastore.key(['Thing', key.id]);
> ```

Why not just use `key` itself instead of creating a new Key object?

Alternatively, you can force the ID type by using:

```
const newKey = datastore.key(['Thing', datastore.int(key.id)]);
```

Comment: I've simplified my example before asking my question. My original problem was with a 'foreign key' column. I had created a column that was populated with `key.id` from another entity. When looking up the reference this would not always yield a result, even though the entity with that ID *did* exist. Turns out this was caused by the key being stored as a string instead of a number. I've updated my question to reflect this. This still seems a bug to me. If the upper limit of JS numbers is an issue I'd expect `datastore.key` to always cast the `id` to a string...

Comment: If I understand you correctly: when storing the ID of another entity I *should* store that as string instead of a number in the datastore, since it could be too large for a Javascript number? If so, it might be worthwhile to mention this in [the datastore documentation](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/entities) because I've never realised this might be an issue. The documentation mentions that an ID can be up to 16 decimals, but doesn't mention this might be too l large for some languages to represent as a number.

Comment: It looks to me like without using `datastore.int()` datastore does **not** do the right thing. It creates another entity with single quotes around the int in the key displayed on said entity.